# How to add flatDir{dirs 'libs'} like on library

Tags: java, android

How to add flatDir{dirs 'libs'} like on library. I want to add .aar file into module implementation(name: 'name', ext: 'aar'). I am able to add aar file into project level but not able to add into module level. Any one please suggest me if it is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try on your `lib/gradle.build`

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":my-project-module")
}
```

So your `lib module` will have `.aar` dependency from `project module`

Look [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 0):

from left side of Android Studio go to  >> project  >> app 
create a folder lib

paste your aar file into it 
right click on aar file and select add as a library